# как запустить .sh где находится php код?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

при попытке ввести команду bash updater.sh (находясь в той же директории)
идет ответ:

```
updater.sh: строка 2: ?php: Нет такого файла или каталога
updater.sh: строка 3: ошибка синтаксиса около неожиданной лексемы `dirname'
updater.sh: строка 3: `require(dirname(__FILE__).'/packages/PackageLoader/include.php');'
```

вот первые строки .sh файла

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/packages/PackageLoader/include.php');

PackageLoader::Get()->setMode('debug');
PackageLoader::Get()->setMode('development');

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/packages/Engine/include.2.6.php');

Engine::Get()->enableErrorReporting();

print "\n";
print "Database updated.\n";

try {
    Engine::GetCache()->clearCache();

    print "Cache cleared.\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Cache clear error!\n";
}

file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/rev.info', date('YmdHis'));
```

тоесть проблема как вижу в том что интерпретатор не понимает php языка. Подскажите как правильно вызывать ету команду, или в чем причина такого ответа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Баш ещё не настолько поехал крышей, что бы понимать php. А судя по коду, там самый натуральный php, даже правильно первая строка прописана.

В целом, в линуксе расширение файла носит сугубо косметическое назначение. Немногие программы переживают по его поводу. То, что у файла sh расширение, ещё не говорит, что его нужно запускать башем.

Как же все запустить. Самый простой способ - просто вызвать через php - `php updater.sh` (возможно, в Вашей системе он уже давно называется php5 или php-cli, это нужно уточнить). Более сложный способ - вначале сделать файл исполняемым (`chmod a+x updater.sh`), а потом просто запустить (`./updater.sh`).

Answer (score 2):

«правильно» вызвать данный скрипт можно двумя способами:

1. непосредственно передать его первым параметром соответствующему интерпретатору:

   ```
   $ php путь_к_скрипту
   ```
2. присвоить файлу со скриптом бит «выполнимости» и запустить его, как и любую другую программу:

   ```
   $ chmod +x путь_к_файлу
   $ ./путь_к_файлу
   ```

во втором случае благодаря т.н. [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)-у система поймёт, какому именно интерпретатору следует передать этот скрипт.

> в чем причина такого ответа

«причина» в том, что интерпретатор, которому вы попытались передать скрипт для выполнения (в данном случае bash), не понимает синтаксис языка, используемого другим интерпретатором (в данном случае php).